# JS c помощью regexp найти в json ключ и изменить его значение

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Столкнулся с задачей -  нужно регуляркой найти в json пару "name" :   "oldName" и заменить "oldName" на "newName"

Придумал пока только так:
data.replace( /"name":\s".*"/g,   '"name": "newName"' );

Но по условию нужно изменить только "oldName", все остальное только помогает найти, что менять
Вместо oldName может быть любой текст

Кто может подкинуть идею?

Comment: Измените `.*` на `[^"]*`. Или `.*?`.

Comment: Спасибо, я изменил .* на .*?.
Но все равно таким образом я заменяю всю пару ключ-значение "имя": "oldName", а мне нужно заменить только значение "oldName"

Comment: Да не вопрос, используйте захватывающие подмаски и обратные ссылки,`data.replace( /("name"\s*:\s*")[^"]*/g, '$1newName');`

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribiżew
Вы настоящий ниндзя, спасибо большое!!!

Comment: Буду смотреть обязательно! Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Используйте

```js
data = data.replace(/("name"\s*:\s*")[^"]*/g, '$1newName');
```

- `("name"\s*:\s*")` - Подмаска №1: `"name"`, 0+ пробельных символов, `:`, 0+ пробельных символов, `"`
- `[^"]*` - ноль и более символов `"`.

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/csa7FN/1).

Пример работы кода:

```js
let data = '"name" : "oldName"';
data = data.replace(/("name"\s*:\s*")[^"]*/g, '$1newName'); 
console.log(data);
```